# Simple Encryption for Multiple Columns in R with Reproducibility

Tags: r, encryption, dplyr

I need to generate simple random keys for multiple columns with the ability to generate the same keys and maybe add more in the future without the old keys changing. Some sample data:

```
data <- data.frame(
  
  tree = c(222222, 123456, 9123456),
  fruit = c(12345, 55555, 123456),
  seed = c(777777, 888888, 999999),
  nutrients = c(12345678, 23456789, 912345678),
  flowers = c(2, 3, 3)
)
```

I have tried the following:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringi)

set.seed(2)

data_ids <- data
arrange(tree, fruit, seed, nutrients) %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(tree_id = paste0(stri_rand_strings(1, 3, "[A-Z]"),
                            stri_rand_strings(1, 3, "[0-9]"),
                            stri_rand_strings(1, 3, "[A-Z]")),
         fruit_id = paste0(stri_rand_strings(1,4, "[A-Z]"),
                             stri_rand_strings(1, 4, "[0-9]")),
         seed_id = stri_rand_strings(1, 10, "[A-Z]"),
         enc_id = stri_rand_strings(1, 10, "[0-9]"))
```

The problem with this method is that each id is not tied to its original. Tree should be tied to tree_id and so on. This method works great for one time use but if I wanted to add a new record I'm not sure the already generated id's would stay the same.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I also tried encryptr but the generated keys are too complicated

Comment: The id's being generated are not taking into consideration the original column just creating a random sequence based on row. tree_id should be associated with tree and so forth.

Comment: Not clear.  May be `data %>% arrange(tree, fruit, seed, nutrients) %>% mutate(across(-flowers, ~ stri_rand_strings(n(), flowers, glue::glue("[{.}]") ), .names = "{.col}_id"))`

Comment: If you need to add `A-Z` as well `data %>% arrange(tree, fruit, seed, nutrients) %>% mutate(across(-flowers, ~ stri_rand_strings(n(), flowers, glue::glue("[A-Z{.}]") ), .names = "{.col}_id"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I have correctly understood what you are trying to do. My guess is that you want to encrypt the values of your columns in a reliable way. We could use a hashing algorithm with a package like {digest}. But we can also use your approach, we just need to make sure that each value is always converted to the same string, so actually it would be "not so random string" if you will.

We can do this by wrapping the existing function into a wrapper and calling `set.seed` before each call to `stri_rand_strings` where the `seed` is the value of each cell.

I understood most of the mappings, but I had to guess the binding of `enc_id` I just mapped it to `nutrients`, but we can change that easily.

Further, `tree_id` contains two identical calls to `stri_rand_strings(tree, 1, 3, "[A-Z]")` and with the approach below this will yield the same string pattern at the beginning and end of each `tree_id`. Probably it is advisable to change the pattern of the last call.

Apart from this, would the approach below solve your problem?

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringi)

# the data
data <- data.frame(
  tree = c(222222, 123456, 9123456),
  fruit = c(12345, 55555, 123456),
  seed = c(777777, 888888, 999999),
  nutrients = c(12345678, 23456789, 912345678),
  flowers = c(2, 3, 3)
)

# lets append a new row to test the approach
data2 <- data %>% 
  add_row(tree = 324325,
          fruit = 871556,
          seed = 1111111,
          nutrients = 61551548, 
          flowers = 4)

# custom function which sets seed before calling stri_rand_strings
seed_rand_string <- function(.seed, .n, .length, .pattern) {
  set.seed(.seed)
  stri_rand_strings(.n, .length, .pattern)
}

data %>% 
  arrange(tree, fruit, seed, nutrients) %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(tree_id = paste0(seed_rand_string(tree, 1, 3, "[A-Z]"),
                          seed_rand_string(tree, 1, 3, "[0-9]"),
                          seed_rand_string(tree, 1, 3, "[A-Z]")),
         fruit_id = paste0(seed_rand_string(fruit, 1, 4, "[A-Z]"),
                           seed_rand_string(fruit, 1, 4, "[0-9]")),
         seed_id = seed_rand_string(seed, 1, 10, "[A-Z]"),
         enc_id = seed_rand_string(nutrients, 1, 10, "[0-9]"))

#> # A tibble: 3 x 9
#> # Rowwise: 
#>      tree  fruit   seed nutrients flowers tree_id   fruit_id seed_id   enc_id   
#>     <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>     <chr>    <chr>     <chr>    
#> 1  123456  55555 888888  23456789       3 UTK773UTK YRIY9639 PUGELDRY… 33355323…
#> 2  222222  12345 777777  12345678       2 KSU468KSU SWTX7878 FVTGKDXV… 82980539…
#> 3 9123456 123456 999999 912345678       3 BHU028BHU UTKI7733 WVGMPGKD… 10060645…

data2 %>% 
  arrange(tree, fruit, seed, nutrients) %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(tree_id = paste0(seed_rand_string(tree, 1, 3, "[A-Z]"),
                          seed_rand_string(tree, 1, 3, "[0-9]"),
                          seed_rand_string(tree, 1, 3, "[A-Z]")),
         fruit_id = paste0(seed_rand_string(fruit, 1, 4, "[A-Z]"),
                           seed_rand_string(fruit, 1, 4, "[0-9]")),
         seed_id = seed_rand_string(seed, 1, 10, "[A-Z]"),
         enc_id = seed_rand_string(nutrients, 1, 10, "[0-9]"))

#> # A tibble: 4 x 9
#> # Rowwise: 
#>      tree  fruit    seed nutrients flowers tree_id   fruit_id seed_id   enc_id  
#>     <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>     <chr>    <chr>     <chr>   
#> 1  123456  55555  888888  23456789       3 UTK773UTK YRIY9639 PUGELDRY… 3335532…
#> 2  222222  12345  777777  12345678       2 KSU468KSU SWTX7878 FVTGKDXV… 8298053…
#> 3  324325 871556 1111111  61551548       4 MQW468MQW AUYE0891 MYFXDMTO… 3068266…
#> 4 9123456 123456  999999 912345678       3 BHU028BHU UTKI7733 WVGMPGKD… 1006064…
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: My team and I have been able to implement this. Thanks!